# How to compare two .txt documents by characters & quantify score, where order is important (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to quantify the similarity between two .txt documents. They are transcriptions, so order is important and it is a measure of inter-rater reliability as opposed to semantic similarity. I would like a score that is meaningful to humans (e.g. out of 100). I have found a lot of answers on here for similar problems, but none that are quite right, so apologies if the answer is indeed somewhere and I've missed it.

The closest I've got is using [dwdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dwdiff) on Linux, which gives the following result (using example text) including a percentage in common:

[image]

However, this [website](https://countwordsfree.com/comparetexts) I found seems to be based at the character level and is therefore a more accurate comparison:

[image]

I cannot find a solution to how they achieve this? Ideally I would like to implement in Python as I'm most familiar with that langauge and can then apply at scale. Or, is there a better solution that I've missed? The highlighting is not necessary. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: check out spacy

Comment: Might be worth having a look at the built-in `difflib` module - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html#differ-objects).

Comment: also checkout fuzzywuzzy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JPI93 mentioned, you may want to check out the [difflib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

```py
import difflib

a = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
b = a.replace('e', '3')

m = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)

print(m.ratio()*100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe fuzzywuzzy is a better choice here. Here are the examples from their Github page. [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

```
Usage

>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process

Simple Ratio

>>> fuzz.ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
    97

Partial Ratio

>>> fuzz.partial_ratio("this is a test", "this is a test!")
    100

Token Sort Ratio

>>> fuzz.ratio("fuzzy wuzzy was a bear", "wuzzy fuzzy was a bear")
    91
>>> fuzz.token_sort_ratio("fuzzy wuzzy was a bear", "wuzzy fuzzy was a bear")
    100

Token Set Ratio

>>> fuzz.token_sort_ratio("fuzzy was a bear", "fuzzy fuzzy was a bear")
    84
>>> fuzz.token_set_ratio("fuzzy was a bear", "fuzzy fuzzy was a bear")
    100
```